# Adding Printer Links on Web page

Tags: css

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to create printer link for end user that they can click on and let them install that printer on their machine.

This command does this:

```
\\server\printer-name
```

When I run this locally it installs the printer, but I want to add that to a link on a web page so that user can click on and do the same thing.

Comment: If the user is on the same network as the printer, it should still work.

Comment: You can do this on Windows XP using Internet Explorer - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307847